# Are ApplicationBeans Methods buffered?

Tags: web-applications, jsf-2, managed-bean

I have a JSF 2.0 WebApp that has one application bean that runs a method for drawing a number for example. I don't want 2 requests to run at the same time so my question is: should I implement any kind of semaphore (and how) or are methods already buffered by the ApplicationBean?

Answer (score 1):

Those methods are absolutely not 'buffered' (I think the word you're looking for is `synchronized`). Or put differently, an application scoped managed bean is not thread-safe.

You either need to make the method synchronized or use an @Singleton @Named bean that gives you finer control over concurrency. In the last case your app would need to run on a server that supports at least the Java EE 6 web profile (Glassfish, JBoss, Resin).